# Which Guru is to be worshipped on the Guru Purnima day by a disciple who's having multiple Gurus?

Tags: guru, festivals

When a person has more than 1 gurus, then at the time of "Guru Pournima", whom should he/she worship.
(some Gurus are still living, but far away located. Other ones are "brahma leen, i.e. left their mortal bodies).

Request guidance over this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79737/discussion-on-question-by-vineet-which-guru-is-to-be-worshipped-on-the-guru-purn).

Comment: the chat page is not existing.

Comment: it was undeleted automatically. Just made available again

Comment: Still it is ... "Page not found"

Comment: Again deleted for inactivity. Posting of messages are necessary to keep the room alive.

Answer (score 1):

Sri Krishna says in BG 4.34, to approach **wise ones/jnanis/REALISED ONES**, serve them and get knowledge.  Here, Sri Krishna did not prohibit Wise men.

> तद्विद्धि प्रणिपातेन परिप्रश्नेन सेवया।
>
> उपदेक्ष्यन्ति ते ज्ञानं ज्ञानिनस्तत्त्वदर्शिनः।।4.34।।
>
> Know that through prostration, iniry and service. The wise ones who
>   have realized the Truth will impart the Knowledge to you.

---

[Bhagavata Purana](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto11/chapter9.html) narrates about avadhUta having 24 Gurus.

So there is nothing wrong in obtaining knowledge various Gurus.  However, one should stick to the ONE Guru, ***who appeals to ONE the most***.